# SQL Server - Dynamic Pivot with 2 Group Variables and 2 Aggregate Calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a dataset that is shaped like this:

[image]

I am trying to convert the data to this format:

[image]

As you can see, I'd like to sum the accounts and revenue (for each month) by State and Account Type. It is important to note that I seek a dynamic solution as these ARE NOT the only values (hard-coding is not an option!).

What SQL query can I write to accomplish this task, dynamically? (as these values are not the only ones present in the complete dataset).

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, dynamic rows is not my question.  Do you need dynamic columns i.e. Accounts, Revenue, EXPENSE, ... ?

Comment: In other words, does your source have more columns other than Accounts and Revenue ?

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your questions...for the purposes of this question, assume that this dataset is the full dataset. In other words, Accounts and Revenue are the only fields of interest.

Comment: You may find https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796651/Client-Side-Multi-Column-Dynamic-Pivot interesting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to keep the columns in order by date, thus the `top 100 percent ... order by`  in the section where we generate the columns

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  ( 
        Select [State]
              ,[AccountType]
              ,B.*
         From YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (concat(''Accounts_'',format([Date],''MM/dd/yyyy'')),Accounts)
                             ,(concat(''Revenue_'' ,format([Date],''MM/dd/yyyy'')),Revenue)
                     ) B  (Item,Value)

       ) A
 Pivot (sum([Value]) For [Item] in (' + Stuff((Select ','+QuoteName('Accounts_'+format([Date],'MM/dd/yyyy')) 
                                                     +','+QuoteName('Revenue_' +format([Date],'MM/dd/yyyy'))
                                                 From (Select top 100 percent [Date] from YourTable Group By [Date] Order by [Date] ) A  
                                                 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]

**If it helps, the generated SQL looks like this:**

```
Select *
 From  ( 
        Select [State]
              ,[AccountType]
              ,B.*
         From YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (concat('Accounts_',format([Date],'MM/dd/yyyy')),Accounts)
                             ,(concat('Revenue_' ,format([Date],'MM/dd/yyyy')),Revenue)
                     ) B  (Item,Value)

       ) A
 Pivot (sum([Value]) For [Item] in ([Accounts_12/31/2017],[Revenue_12/31/2017],[Accounts_01/31/2018],[Revenue_01/31/2018]) ) p
```